# PHP code inside echo

Tags: php, magento, echo

I have following code which displays the price in Magento.

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
```

I have to put this code inside echo instead and I can't get it to work.

I am trying

```
echo "$this->getPriceHtml ($_product)";
```

It just displays () on the page.

I tried other combinations and I can't come up with anything else.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Using single quotes will prevent $vars to be interpreted:

```
echo '$this->getPriceHtml ($_product)';
```

Or escape the $ sign:

```
echo "\$this->getPriceHtml (\$_product)";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Or if by echo-ing you mean that you want to get something like

```
The price is 123.00
```

then do:

```
echo "The price is {$this->getPriceHtml($_product)}";
```

or even :

```
echo sprintf("The price is %s", $this->getPriceHtml($_product));
```

Answer (score 0):

why not you are using this ?

$_product->getFinalPrice() or

if you want in formatted order then why you are not using this
number_format($pr->getPrice(), 2)

and if you want price with currency format then you can use this also
Mage::helper('core')->currency($pr->getPrice());

Hope it will help you.
:)